# How to get all post titles starting with numbers and symbols?

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts, title, get-the-title

I want to get all posts which are starting with a number (0-9) or symbols, in a list. I managed to get it work for letters, but this one is harder for me. Can someone help me out please?

I tried adding this in my existing code, but it didn't work:

```
$this_char = strtoupper(mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'));
if (strpos('0123456789',$this_char) !== false) $this_char = '0-9';
if ($this_char != $last_char) {
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

      $first_char = 'A';

    $postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT      ID
    FROM        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
    ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char));

    if ($postids) {
    $args=array(
      'post__in' => $postids,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
      'orderby'=> 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     echo 'test test '. $first_char;

      while ($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post(); 

?>     
        <li><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>        </li>
        <?php

      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Note: I want all of these symbols and numbers on 1 page.

Comment: No one who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the `posts_where` filter and add your condition to the query:

```
add_filter('posts_where', function($where){
  global $wpdb;
  return "{$where} AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title REGEXP '^[0-9\$\@\!\?\%]'";
                                // add other symbols in the regex above ^
});
```

Then do your query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(...);
```

You may want to remove the filter after you get the results (make it a normal function so you can pass the name to `remove_filter`).

Comment: So I only have to put the the first snippet on functions.php and then just refresh the site? What do I have to put on `$first_char`?